# Image hosting with public API, management console and autoresize, any recommendations?

Tags: image, api, rest, hosting, storage

I'm trying to find appropriate image hosting for my mobile app. I have been using flickr but it's not possible to proceed with it because due to (new?) terms and conditions I'm not allowed to upload images that do not produced by me.

I'm using the following flickr features:

- Management console to upload images and assign tags to them.
- REST API to get images by tag and sort them by date added. Anonymous or public key to allow only read data.
- Autoresize because I have a mobile app and want to display a list of thumbnails.
- Ok for commercial usage.

I have been looking at:

- [imageshack.us](http://imageshack.us/) - buggy and unstable. For some reason the order of images differs from time to time.
- [cloudinary.com](http://cloudinary.com/) - it seems that the only way to get a list of images is to use a private API key which implies that someone could use this key to erase all the photos. So it's insecure.
- [uploadcare.com](https://uploadcare.com/) - does not have admin console.
- [api.imgur.com](http://api.imgur.com/) - too complicated for commercial usage: register app, register wit Mashape.. but correct me if I'm wrong.
- [minus.com](http://minus.com/pages/api) - doesn't have resize and anonymous access to API.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Update: ended up using [api.imgur.com](http://api.imgur.com) as a storage and management tool for images. Unfortunately response time for about 600 images is very slow (10 - 20 sec.) and returning json is heavy (147 kb). So I've built middleware layer on EC2 to filter out redundant json attributes and cache result json on S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use, you can use Amazon S3. It is great and it just works perfectly!

A possible cheaper option is Google. Google docs now supports all file types, so you can load the images up to a Google docs folder, and share the folder for public access. The URL's are kind of long though.
There are various options for resizing etc and it's Google so obviously their API is stable and perfect.

Google only charges USD5/year for 20GB. There is a full API for uploading photos, docs etc.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at S3 and write if it's acceptable for me.

Comment: Update: ended up using [api.imgur.com](http://api.imgur.com) as a storage and management tool for images. Unfortunately response time for about 600 images is very slow (10 - 20 sec.) and returning json is heavy (147 kb). So I've built middleware layer on EC2 to filter out redundant json attributes and cache result json on S3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you would like to have a self hosted image hosting service for your apps.

If yes, I would say check out ImageS3, https://github.com/images3/images3-play. An image hosting service run on top of Amazon S3 and it is like other image hosting service you have been looking at, the only different is that it is open source.